# Updating a table in oracle with data from another table that has duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two Oracle tables, table car and table automobile.I am updating Car to add two fields that exist in Automobile make and model. Both tables have 3 foriegn keys, Code1, Code 2 and Code 3 that link them where I need at least 1 of the keys to match to update the table and the columns can be blank so we would have to be careful there. The codes are unique to each record except in the case of duplicates which I mention below. To visualize let me make the tables here:

Table Car

```
   ID | Code1 | Code2| Code3| Color | Salesman
    1  1A2B3C   555HGG H1H1H1  Red     John
    2  2H4H6H   777JHH J1J1J1  Blue    Steve
    3  3J7K4A   222QYY I1I1I1  Yellow  Maria
    4                  K2K2K2  Pink    Clara
    5           999YII         Red     Tim
```

Table Automobile

```
Code1| Code2| Code3 | Make  | Model  | ID
1A2B3C 555HGG H1H1H1  Nissan  Sentra   234
2H4H6H        J1J1J1  Chevy   Malibu   235
              K2K2K2  Nissan  Maxima   236
              K2K2K2  Nissan  Maxima   237
       999YII         Ford    Focus    238
```

Updated Table Car:

```
   ID | Code1 | Code2| Code3| Color | Salesman | Make | Model
    1  1A2B3C   555HGG H1H1H1  Red     John      Nissan Sentra
    2  2H4H6H   777JHH J1J1J1  Blue    Steve     Chevy  Malibu
    3  3J7K4A   222QYY I1I1I1  Yellow  Maria
    4                  K2K2K2  Pink    Clara     Nissan Maxima
    5           999YII          Red    Tim       Ford   Focus
```

So Table Car initially does not have the Make and Model fields but we need to take that from table Automobile. Assume the fields exist in the table now and just need to be populated. Also Duplicate records with unique IDs are possible as you see in the Nissan Maxima example in table automobile. In that case I would just need one of the records only doesn't matter which since ID from Automobile is irrelevant and not needed. The Two ID fields have no connection. At least 1 of the code fields will be populated there will never be a situation where all are null. I am aware this is a somewhat messy question so if you need clarification ask away and I will make adjustments to my OP. Also once again this is for Oracle so keep that in mind. Any help would be appreciated, this has been nagging me for days.

Comment: That's an ugly data model you have there. Questions: Is it ever possible that a row from Car matches a row from table Automobile on Code1, but they have different Code2 (can there ever be a conflict like that)? I already see that rows can match on Code1 and the row in one table has a non-null Code2 but the Code2 is null in the other table. Also, when there are duplicate in Automobile, are you guaranteed that the Make and Model will match, and only the ID will be different?

Comment: For your first question yes but the conflict will be a null field. That's why I said only 1 field has to match. If one code matches and others don't, it's because it's null in one of the tables. So Code1 could be the same in both tables for a record but Code 2 can exist for one and be bull for the other. As you said this is ugly. Forgot your other question. Yes if there are duplicates only ID will differ.

Comment: I may go back to the drawing board with this. The reason the data is so weird is because it comes from two different relational databases. Sybase and Oracle. I think I am going to create another post asking the community how they would best tackle a transferring of such data.

Answer (score 0):

The following uses `row_number()` to get one row and then matches on the codes:

```
select c.*, a.make, a.model
from car c left join
     (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by code1, code2, code3 order by id) as seqnum
      from automobile a
     ) a
     on (c.code1 = a.code1 or c.code1 is null and a.code1 is null) and
        (c.code2 = a.code2 or c.code2 is null and a.code2 is null) and
        (c.code3 = a.code2 or c.code3 is null and a.code3 is null) and
        a.seqnum = 1
```

Comment: I ran it, running very slow. Couple hundred thousand records it is sifting through at a pace of about 100 every 30 seconds. I assume little can be done to speed it up correct?

Comment: @Sigma - This doesn't look like an `UPDATE` statement anyway, so even if you can speed it up, how will that help?

Comment: I assumed this was the select criteria as part of an update statement so I was running it as a select first to see what it comes up with. I assumed that was his intentions anyway.

Comment: @Sigma - I understand that, but you will see that `UPDATE` comes with its own execution time hurdles, often not caused by the `SELECT` part alone. (Although in this case the join may be a significant bottleneck.)

Comment: Ok I see so you are saying any time execution time issues I face now will potentially only get worse using the above criteria for an update statement?

Answer (score 0):

Joins on `OR` conditions are pretty slow since they can't take advantage of indexes on your columns. (It would help if you had indexes on `Code1`, `Code2` and `Code3` in your tables.) I would rather split the job into three separate updates, using one column at a time. Also, in the second and third update I would check for `NULL`s in the new columns to make sure I don't update a row to the same values it contains already (that may seem like a minor thing, but undo and redo may add significant overhead, over and above the redundant assignments).

Since you need to de-duplicate the `Automobile` table, you may be better off creating a temporary table (since you are going to use it three times). Something like:

```
create global temporary table auto
on commit preserve rows    -- if you want to commit after each update
as (
     select code1, code2, code3, min(make) as make, min(model) as model
     from   automobile
     group by code1, code2, code3
   )
```

Then the second update, using `code2` (`code3` would be similar, and `code1` would not need the `where` clause). You will see that I prefer the `merge` statement, but you can use `update` with a join.

```
merge into car c
  using auto a
  on (c.code2 = a.code2)
when matched then update
     set c.make  = a.make,
         c.model = a.model
     where c.make is null
;
```

Comment: And what if there is Nissan Maxima, Nissan Altima, Nissan Centra in the table? the picked model will be random. If building a temp table I would suggest doing DISTINCT column_list..., min(id) as id. Not sure if you can use indexes on temp table. @Sigma, If the reason to just combine data, you might want to use regular intermediate table and apply indexes to speed up your query.

Comment: Unfortunately I have limited write access to my environment. I will try to get more access and try this.

Comment: @LeonidAlzhin - This is why I asked for clarification, in Comments below the original post, before I created and posted a suggested solution. Please see there.

Comment: @LeonidAlzhin - I may be wrong, but I assume the syntax for de-duplicating (whether using SELECT DISTINCT or GROUP BY) is irrelevant. If the result is the same, and one would otherwise be more "expensive" than the other, the optimizer would take care of it. I prefer GROUP BY because perhaps in `Automobile` one row has both make and model but in the other it only has make... taking `min(make)` will pick up the non-null value. I hope this makes sense!

Comment: @Sigma - even if you can't create a temporary table and you just use the grouped version of `Automobile` in `merge` statements, I think you will still be better off if you (1) de-duplicate before attempting to use the table; and (2) use three successive "updates" (`merge` statements) instead of trying to do it all in one statement, due to the issue of joining on `OR`-linked conditions.

Comment: Thanks @mathguy I will try it your way first as soon as I get access and let you know how it goes.